# check if NSdictionary - NESTED key is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, key, nsdictionary

I am pulling json data ... and can't change how it comes out

(CASE 1) most times it comes out like this

collection1{

-paragraph {
href: "x",
text: "y"
},

title: "title"

},

(CASE 2)sometimes it comes out like this

paragraph: "y"

title: "title"

},

...

i do this -> NSString * paragraphText = [[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"]  objectForKey:@"text"];

to get the data in CASE 1

but for case two i need to check if the NESTED key -> [[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"]  objectForKey:@"text"]; exists

if it doesn't then just use -> [[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"]

i have tried so many ways to check if the key exists ... i.e

1. id obj = [[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"] objectForKey:@"text"];
       if (obj == [NSNull null]) {
2. if (![[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"] objectForKey:@"text"])  and other variations of the above ...

i get the error -> [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145731f0'

i know that the key does not exist ...

How do i check if a nested key exists? .. this way i can try another key access the data?

Comment: data is not coming in NSDictionary format, it is actually a NSString, check data again.

Comment: Eike's answer might solve your problem. The error implies that you're using "ObjectForKey" on a string, and not a dictionary, so you'll need to check if you're working with a dictionary or a string first.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the paragraph's type, if it's a dictionary it's case 1

```
id paragraph = postDictionary[@"paragraph"];
if([paragraph isMemberOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
{
    // case 1
    NSString *textFromParagraph = ((NSDictionary*)paragraph)[@"text"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eike, Rishi and Adama. I ended up doing

NSDictionary * paragraph = postDictionary[@"paragraph"];

```
    if ([paragraph isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {[@"text"];
        blogPost.content    = [[postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"]  objectForKey:@"text"];
    }else{
        blogPost.content    = [postDictionary objectForKey:@"paragraph"];
    }
```

I learnt something.

Thank you :D